# QR Code Scanning on Windows Phone 8.1 using HTML, CSS and JS

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8.1, phonegap-plugins, zxing

I'm doing project using JavaScript, HTML, CSS for **Windows Phone 8.1**. And I have to integrate QR Code scanning feature on my app. Please help me on this.
I have researched lot but all the samples are based only on Native C# and WP8.0/Silverlight apps.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Please [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting any question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently had to solve that Issue in a WinRT Tablet app that was built with WinJS. After some research, I finally found [this excelent post by Vinicius Linck](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/20140610201847-102625795-windows-8-store-apps-javascript-and-barcode-scanner). The sample code in [his github repo](https://github.com/vinnylinck/CordovaW8BarcodeDemo) got me finally started.

The basic idea is that you [zxing.net](https://zxingnet.codeplex.com/)  to capture the camera stream into a HTML Video element. Then you "mirror" that element onto a Canvas. Using a timer, you'll then just send the canvas content to the zxing library.

At least in a WinJS Windows Store App, this approach worked perfectly. Just make to sure to read the code [in this js file carefully.](https://github.com/vinnylinck/CordovaW8BarcodeDemo/blob/master/platforms/windows8/www/plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner/src/windows8/CameraHandler.js)

Comment: Thank You Andre Kraemer. I got success implementing it on Windows Phone 8.1 That works perfect!!  :) 
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/20140610201847-102625795-windows-8-store-apps-javascript-and-barcode-scanner

Comment: Your welcome. It would be great, if you could mark my answer as the excepted answer then. Thanks